# mapping for msg.sender doesn't seem to work

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens, contract-deployment

state Variable is this : `mapping(address=>uint) public userVotes;`

now i have a function :

```
function votePresident(uint _id) external {
        presidents[_id-1].voteCount++;
        userVotes[msg.sender] = _id;
        Voter(msg.sender, _id, userVotes[msg.sender]);
    }
```

the last line is an event. So What happens here is after executing this function, I put an address of the executer in a mapping as a key and value as he passed in. Then I log it.

I have another function where I use this userVotes

```
function getPresident(uint _index) public view returns (uint, string, uint, string, uint) {
        President storage president = presidents[_index];
   return (president.voteCount, president.hashImage, president.id, president.name, userVotes[msg.sender] );
    }
```

look at the return line the last parameter, `userVotes[msg.sender]` . Unfonrtunatelly, it always returns 0. I don't know why it does that. I checked the log after executing the first function and I didn't see 0. i just saw the actual value. Please help . If I call the getPresident funcction in remix, it returns the actual value and not 0.

Comment: Have you tried to simplify your code to isolate the parts you think are broken? Try building a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In general, you are using `msg.sender` just fine in these situations from what I can see.

Comment: The question is why the same code works on remix .

Comment: Compared to what? I don't think you mentioned which platform this code is failing...

Comment: I'm using web3 to make the calls to contract. When I deploy the contract, and Try to test it using remix, it works on remix, but when I call the same function getPresident stated above,  userVotes[msg.sender] is always 0.

Comment: Add a link to your contract deployment. Do you know if your transactions are successfully mined?

Comment: So `getPresident` seems to work. The thing that doesn't work is your JavaScript code that calls it. You haven't shared that code, but my shot-in-the-dark guess is that you're not passing a `from` address.

Comment: I think you guess it right, my friend. I'm not passing from. It's an free function and I'm using it as "call()". can these view functions also be passed "from:account" from web3?

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question to help others who may run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone Might need it.

Sometimes you may forget to pass an account when you're actually calling a free method that's just returning something. In my case, I was calling a free (no-gas) function and because I didn't use the send transaction, I was forgetting to pass the account name. You can pass the account to the call function as you'd do for the send function.